# Generic type argument

Tags: scala, types

I have the following trait:

```
trait F{
   type T
}
```

and

```
trait C[T]{
   def getF: F{ type T = //I want the outer T}
}
```

Is there a way to refer to the generic type argument without introducing helper `type` variable and renaming the type parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like in Dotty you can do so (see http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/internals/higher-kinded-v2.html) :

```
trait C[type T]{ self =>
   def getF: F{ type T = self.T }
}
```

Otherwise for the current scala version I don't know if it is feasible to do better than introducing an helper `type` variable:

```
trait C[T]{
   type A = T
   def getF: F{ type T = A }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you weren't so inclined to call all types `T`, you could just do

```
trait C[Foo] {
  def getF: F { type T = Foo }
}
```